# Browsing inside Ajax response

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm new to jquery & Ajax.

I have a php file with jquery inside it, which loads content from another php file on selection of a date

```
    $("#datepicker3").change(function(){
        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "ptreport1.php",
                data: 'ptdate=' + $(this).val(),
                success: function(resultt){
                    $('#searchr').html(resultt);
                    $("#searchr").show();
                }
                });
});
```

The issue I'm facing is contents in ptreport1.php has links (pagination) contained to browsing scope of that php file. When the user clicks on those links he is directed out of the original page ajax content is loaded from.
Is there anyway to prevent that and load content in original page.

> Update # 2.

After ediding the codes with preventDefault, following is my jquery

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {    
$("#searchr").hide(); 
$(function() {
$('#datepicker3' ).datepicker({
changeMonth: true,
changeYear: true,
dateFormat: 'dd M yy'
});
});
    $("#datepicker3").change(function(){
    var myValue = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "ptreport1.php",
                data: 'ptdate=' + $(this).val(),
                success: function(resultt){
                    $('#searchr').html(resultt);
                    console.log('html.resultt');
                    $("#searchr").show();
                $('.pagination-link').click(function(e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                       //Another AJAX call to load the content here.
                       var page = $("#pagediv").html();
                       var timestamp =$("#timediv").html();
                       var dataString = 'page='+ page + '&timestamp='+ timestamp;
                               $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "ptreport1.php",
                data: dataString,
                success: function(resultt){
                    $('#searchr').html(resultt);
                    console.log('html.resultt');
                    $("#searchr").show();
                }
                });
                    });    
                }

                });
});  
});
</script>
```

and ptreport1.php

```
<?php

/* 
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
include "core.php";
connectdb();
$page = $_GET['page'];
$timestamp = $_GET['timestamp'];
$ptdate = $_POST['ptdate'];
if(isset($timestamp)){
$ptdate = date('d M Y', $_GET['timestamp']);
}else{    
$timestamp =  strtotime($ptdate);  
}
 if(!isset($page)){
     $page=1;
 }
    if($page=="" || $page<=0)$page=1;
$numresults = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT patient.firstname, patient.lastname, appointment.charge FROM patient INNER JOIN appointment ON  patient.id = appointment.patientid WHERE DATE_FORMAT(appointment.date, '%d %b %Y')='".$ptdate."'")or die("error querying");
$numrows = mysqli_num_rows($numresults);
    $num_items = $numrows; //changable
    $items_per_page= 5;
    $num_pages = ceil($num_items/$items_per_page);
    if($page>$num_pages)$page= $num_pages;
    $limit_start = ($page-1)*$items_per_page;    
    $npage = $page+1;
$numresults = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT patient.firstname, patient.lastname, appointment.charge FROM patient INNER JOIN appointment ON  patient.id = appointment.patientid WHERE DATE_FORMAT(appointment.date, '%d %b %Y')='".$ptdate."' LIMIT $limit_start, $items_per_page")or die("error querying");
$numrows = mysqli_num_rows($numresults);
if($numrows==0){
    echo "Sorry, No results for $ptdate.";
    exit();
}
echo "<p><table>";
while($msdrow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($numresults)){
        $charge= $msdrow['charge'];
        $fname= $msdrow['firstname'];
        $lname= $msdrow['lastname'];
      // $fullname = $fname." ".$lname;
echo "<tr><td>$fname</td><td>$lname</td><td>$charge</td></tr>";
$totalcharge = $totalcharge+$charge;
    }
echo "<b><tr><td colspan=\"2\">Total Charge</td><td>$totalcharge</td></tr></b></table></p>";
echo "<div id='pagediv' >";
echo "$page</div>";
echo "<div id='timediv' >";
echo "$timestamp</div>";  
  echo "<p align=\"center\">";   
    if($page>1)
    {
      $ppage = $page-1;
      echo "<a href=\"ptreport1.php?timestamp=$timestamp&amp;page=$ppage\" class=\"pagination-link\">&#171;PREV</a> ";
    }
    if($page<$num_pages)
    {
      $npage = $page+1;
      echo "<a href=\"ptreport1.php?timestamp=$timestamp&amp;page=$npage\" class=\"pagination-link\">Next&#187;</a>";
    }
    echo "<br/>$page/$num_pages<br/>";
echo "</p>";
```

What am i doing wrong here, since it after second click it jumps out of ajax directs to original php page.

Thanx

Answer (score 0):

You would need to set onclick event handlers on the pagination links after loading the content in ptreport1.php. You'll need to change .pagination-link to match the links in the content you are loading.

```
success: function(resultt){
                    $('#searchr').html(resultt);
                    $("#searchr").show();
                    $('.pagination-link').click(function(e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                       //Another AJAX call to load the content here.
                    });
                }
```

Comment: Thanx, The issue I'm facing now is it jumps out of original page to linked php pag after 2nd click

Comment: I updated the question with javascript file and ptreport1.php

Comment: $('.pagination-link') must match the pagination link in ptreport1.php. I would need to see the links in the content you are loading to tell you what should go there.

Comment: Hi, I have appended ptreport1.php to the original question here. pls have a look. Thanx